# How to receive image file to API server (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I want to build API server by node.js,
and I want to post image file to my API server.

I was able to write GET method logic in my code
but, I have no idea write POST method logic.
Please help me.

↓My code (node.js)

```
// preprocessing
  // import library
  var express    = require('express');
  var app        = express();
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var fs         = require('fs');
  // post setting
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  // port setting
  var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  // express setting
  var router = express.Router();
  router.use(function(req, res, next) {
      console.log('Something is happening.');
      next();
  });

// main
 // GET method
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.json({ message: 'Hello World' });
 });
 // POST method
 router.route('/image')
  .post(function(req1, res1) { 
      res1.json({image : req1.body});
   });

  // routing
  app.use('/api/v1', router);
  // start server
  app.listen(port);
  console.log('listen on port ' + port);
```

↓ Test curl command(GET)

```
curl -k -x GET "http://XXX/api/v1"
```

↓ curl result(GET)

```
"message" :"Hello World"
```

↓ Test curl command(POST)

```
curl -k -X POST -F "images_file=@test01.jpg" "http://XXXX/api/v1/image"
```

↓ curl result(POST)

```
"image" :""
```

Comment: Standard answer for all things node.js file upload: make your life easier and use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: >>cviejo thank you for comment.I try to use multer

Answer (score 0):

client side

```
<form action="/pictures/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select an image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="image"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

server side use multer package and write post route as following

```
var express = require('express')
  , router = express.Router()
  , multer = require('multer')

var uploading = multer({
  dest: __dirname + '../public/uploads/',
})

router.post('/upload', uploading, function(req, res) {

})

module.exports = router
```

[for more detail take a look at this link image example](https://www.terlici.com/2015/05/16/uploading-files-locally.html)